# strange dots and lines in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

been getting these strange ghostly dots and lines appearing at random in a windows 7 install.

they appear at random, and in different amounts. when they dop appear on screen, scrolling can cause them to "artifact" for lack of a better word and spread over the screen.

the laptop in question is a thinkpad t410. it has been sent back to lenovo and had both the motherboard and the panel replaced (even though the lines show up on external monitors as well) it has also had a clean install of windows 7 done, but to no avail.

anybody seen anything like this before, or know how to remedy it?

[image: strange lines]

Comment: Well its not your screen acting up.. and given that you got that with print screen.. it must be the driver or something.. really odd

Comment: yeah, i really cant figure it out. especially given a format and clean install, with freshly updated drivers, right from lenovo's website :/

Comment: It is a notebook yea?I missed that.. damn.. must be GFX card problem.. I would call Technical up if you still got warranty and get it sorted.. If it is not crashing out, its not going to memory leaks.. so it has to be GPU acting up.. overheating lately ?

Comment: I agree with @ppumkin's opinion. It's probably a rendering problem cause by some fault in some silicon somewhere. However, you may want to rule out rootkits and misbehaving applications with a transparent window first. Run some tools from the sysinternals suite and see if there's anything funny going on.

Comment: Having it via the printscreen means it probably is not a video memory issue, it still could be a video render issue. The description sounded some like the systems own rendering (other software messing with it) or minor graphics driver issue.  SO what happens when you turn off Areo ,and use the Classic theme ?  What happens when you run from a boot disk that is not in that system?  like one of the many flash or cd boot disks with testing tools on it?

Comment: @ppumkin thats the strange part, i just got it back from lenovo, where they supposedly replaced both the panel and the motherboard (which would i assume include the onboard graphics)

Comment: @adam well it has to go back then :( when it ocmes back , sell it and get something else.. just saying, I did a similar things with HP g6 that went back and forth 6 times... never ending..

Comment: its not a personal laptop, and thinkpads are the standard for our staff.  lemon perhaps, but it wont be replaced with anything but a thinkpad. ...back to lenovo it goes.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a problem with the video RAM.

Comment: Don't let lenovo jerk you over. Tell them you want a replacement or they'll keep doing "minor fixes" until your warranty is up. =D

Comment: yeah - gettign a full motherboard replacement (again) and hoping that solves the issue. wanted to see if anyone figured it was a software thing.

Comment: Your computer is probably haunted

Comment: got the laptop back from lenovo, turns out faulty motherboard/graphic combo was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved, as per above. thanks for the help.

only thing haunting that laptop was windows ;)

Comment: you might want to state what exactly fixed as an answer, rather than having people dig through the comments

Comment: As @JourneymanGeek said, please clarify your answer (specify what helped).  Additionally, please pick your words a bit more carefully (ex. haunting???).

Comment: problem solved by having lenovo replace the motherboard and GPU. the haunting reference was to Aram Kocharyan's comment.